# How to changing value in $array2 without referring $array1?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

Consider the following PHP code segment.

```
$array1 = array(1,20);
$x = &$array1[1];
$array2 = $array1;
$array2[1] = 22;
print_r($array1[1]); // Output is 22
```

Here, `$array2` is not referencing to `$array1`, but how to change value in `$array2` by changing value of `$array1`?

Comment: Hey you may be interested in this post that I just made which is based off this post and goes into detail about why you are seeing this behavior. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081106/assign-by-reference-bug

Answer (score 0):

If you want `$array2` to  be a reference of `$array1` then you do the same thing as with `$x`.

```
$array2 = &$array1;
```

Now anything you change in either `$array1` or `$array2` is visible in both arrays since `$array2` is just a reference to `$array1`.

---

**Update**

Thinking about it, what you may be looking at is a way to change a value, but still have a full copy of the arrays. This is doable with an object.

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$array1 = array(1, 20);
$array1[1] = $obj;
$array1[1]->color = 22;

$array2 = $array1;
$array2[1]->color = 33;

echo $array1[1]->color;  // prints 33
```

This is because objects are always copied by reference, whereas numbers and strings are copied as is.

Comment: I think his question though he may not know it is a little more indepth. array2 for the index of 1 is actually now a pointer as shown by array1 changing when array2 is changed even though it is not a reference to array1.

Comment: Yes, internally the language may use a copy on write methodology to avoid many otherwise useless copies.

Comment: In this case I would say that is very dangerous. I personally would not expect the 2nd index of array2 to be a pointer to array1 when it's not assigned as such.